# Get rows where grouped column has a min/median/max value on a two-column group by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please consider the following problem. We group by in pandas (in this case, it's necessary to group by on two columns). We then want to form a data frame consisting of the low row of each group, middle row of each group, and high row of each group (the groups always have size 3 in my problem). The low/middle/high is evaluated with respect to one of the columns that we grouped by (in this case column B).

As an example, we can use

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"ID" : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], "B" : [1,3,5,2,4,6,3,7,8], "C" : [3,2,4,1,6,5,3,2,4]})
df.groupby(["ID", "B"])
```

I would now like to obtain the minimum, middle, and maximum rows of each group according to the value of "B". The grouped dataframe looks like

```
ID B C
1  1 3
   3 2
   5 4
2  2 1
   4 6
...
```

I would like to obtain a dataframe of the first row of each group, the middle row of each group, and the last row of each group
So I want, for the case of the smallest row, a dataframe that looks like

```
ID B C
1  1 3
2  2 1
3  3 3
```

An alternative/better way to perform this task that doesn't use groupby would also be appreciated.

Please note that in my problem, we *must* group by column B - so not including column B in the groupby isn't something I can do. In my problem, there will only ever be 3 groups for B after grouping on A - so the grouping on two columns is necessary.

Please note that  the fact that I have grouped by `B` and want to use `B` to evaluate my min/median/max is what makes my problem different to others I have found asked on this site.

Comment: I don't understand it, why you get the row two in the final dataframe?

Comment: "*we must group by column B*" this seems incorrect, if you do that all your groups will only have **one** row: `for _, g in df.groupby(['ID', 'B']): print(g, end='\n\n')`

Answer (score 0):

You should only group by `A`. Using `B` in the `groupby` would generate groups with only a single row, which isn't useful.

`B` can eventually be used to **sort** the values if this is not already the case.

Then perform a [`groupby.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nth.html):

```
g = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)

# or, if the values need to be sorted by B
g = df.sort_values(by='B').groupby('ID', as_index=False)

out_low = g.nth(0)
out_middle = g.nth(1)
out_high = g.nth(2) # or nth(-1)
```

Output:

```
# out_low
   ID  B  C
0   1  1  3
3   2  2  1
6   3  3  3

# out_middle
   ID  B  C
1   1  3  2
4   2  4  6
7   3  7  2

# out_high
   ID  B  C
2   1  5  4
5   2  6  5
8   3  8  4
```

Comment: I stated in my question that it is necessary to group by `B` since while there might be more than 3 rows per `A` group, there is only ever three `B` groups within each `A` group. How do you deal with this case?

Comment: @MariaC As explained in my comment and answer, grouping by B makes no sense, at least with the provided example. Please provide the complete expected output. Also provide an additional example demonstrating an input/output for the case with more than 3 rows (Note however that your question described "*the groups always have size 3 in my problem*", which seems to contradict your comment)

Comment: Can you please clarify with a better example?